# Using headers when reading from and editing CSV file with ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

Let's say I am using code like this to make inline edits of CSV file:

```
CSV.open(fn, 'r+') do |f|
  old_pos = f.pos
  while r = f.shift
    if r[0] == 'NOT_PROCESSED'
      f.seek(old_pos)
      r[0] = 'PASSED       ' # pay attention to the padding spaces!
      f << r
    end

    old_pos = f.pos
  end
end
```

Is there a way to somehow use headers with this approach? Like for example r['STATUS']? How should I rewrite code to make this possible?

Comment: The idea to edit csv-files in place seem quite dangerous to me. I would either write to a new file, or use some dbm-database when really need to do in-edting of a file.

Answer (score 1):

[`CSV.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) has a third parameter called `options`, where you can add [various](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) options, including `:headers`:

> **:headers**
>   If set to `:first_row` or `true`, the initial row of the CSV file will be treated as a row of headers. If set to an `Array`, the contents will be used as the headers. If set to a `String`, the `String` is run through a call of `::parse_line` with the same `:col_sep`, `:row_sep`, and `:quote_char` as this instance to produce an Array of headers. This setting causes `#shift` to return rows as `CSV::Row` objects instead of Arrays and `#read` to return `CSV::Table` objects instead of an Array of Arrays.

```
CSV.open(fn, 'r+', headers: true) do |f|
  old_pos = f.pos
  while r = f.shift
    if r['STATUS'] == 'NOT_PROCESSED'
      f.seek(old_pos)
      r['STATUS'] = 'PASSED       ' # pay attention to the padding spaces!
      f << r
    end

    old_pos = f.pos
  end
end
```